# How to turn WiFi off/on when in/out a car?

Tags: wi-fi, bluetooth, connection-issues

My phone WiFi connects automatically to hotspots (of my cable provider) which is very convenient except when I'm driving (where connections are disrupted all the time). Is there an easy way to configure WiFi to be OFF while driving and then back ON when out of the car (e.g. depend on car Bluetooth connection)?

I tried the Automate app, and it seems to work fine, but it's tricky to configure and it triggers the battery usage system notification (Android 8) all the time.

Comment: Do you place your phone in a holder when you are driving? Do you use a Bluetooth connection to your car (e.g. hands-free profile)? Is there a Bluetooth device in your car which could be used for detecting that you are in/next to your car?

Comment: The Automate app (or another like it, such as Tasker) is probably what we would recommend. Maybe you'd have a better experience with another similar app, but I don't think they're much simpler to configure.

Comment: I'm not placing the phone in a holder. The car/phone are connected via Bluetooth. I did try the Automate app, but it has issues (won't follow the bluetooth connection change even when it's running, perhaps some permissions or something else which I could configure on my old S6 phone, but not on a new S9).